# VB.net outlook form region listview data to userproperties

Tags: vb.net, listview, outlook

Right I'm new to programming outlook with vb.net hence why I'm here.
I've created an outlook add-in with a form region for Task objects containing a listview
That value list contains 4 columns which the user adds some text to.
Each item added to the listview will populate outlook user properties on exit, I've currently programmed this as per sub item (column) to its own user property using items index as an identifier (not sure if this is the best way but working so far)
What I now need to do is populate the listview with the task user properties values when the object is reopened.

I'm thing on the lines of finding the last listview item index number and then using this number as a range to find the other properties, not sure if this is the best way or how to achieve it but any help would be most welcome.

My form region code is below

Thanks in advance

Public Class FormRegion1

```
Dim obTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim obDisID As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisCustCom As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisDHCom As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisUser As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisTime As Outlook.UserProperty
```

## Region "Form Region Factory"

```
<Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Task)> _
<Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("test3.FormRegion1")> _
Partial Public Class FormRegion1Factory

    ' Occurs before the form region is initialized.
    ' To prevent the form region from appearing, set e.Cancel to true.
    ' Use e.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
    Private Sub FormRegion1Factory_FormRegionInitializing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionInitializingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormRegionInitializing

    End Sub

End Class
```

## End Region

```
'Occurs before the form region is displayed. 
'Use Me.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
'Use Me.OutlookFormRegion to get a reference to the form region.
Private Sub FormRegion1_FormRegionShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormRegionShowing
    obTask = Me.OutlookItem

End Sub

'Occurs when the form region is closed.   
'Use Me.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
'Use Me.OutlookFormRegion to get a reference to the form region.
Private Sub FormRegion1_FormRegionClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormRegionClosed

    For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        obDisID = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisID" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisID.Value = itm.Index
        obDisCustCom = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisCustCom" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisCustCom.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(1).Text
        obDisDHCom = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisDHCom" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisDHCom.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(2).Text
        obDisUser = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisUser" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisUser.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(3).Text
        obDisTime = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisTime" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisTime.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(4).Text
    Next

    obTask.Save()

End Sub
```

Comment: Seem to have got it working added a line to For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items to save the last item.index to a userproperty then use this property to loop through the properties on load. still would like to know if there is a better way that anyone knows of

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class FormRegion1

```
Dim obTask As Outlook.TaskItem
Dim obDisID As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisTotal As Outlook.UserProperty

Dim obDisCustCom As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisDHCom As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisUser As Outlook.UserProperty
Dim obDisTime As Outlook.UserProperty
```

## Region "Form Region Factory"

```
<Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Task)> _
<Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("test3.FormRegion1")> _
Partial Public Class FormRegion1Factory

    ' Occurs before the form region is initialized.
    ' To prevent the form region from appearing, set e.Cancel to true.
    ' Use e.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
    Private Sub FormRegion1Factory_FormRegionInitializing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionInitializingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormRegionInitializing

    End Sub

End Class
```

## End Region

```
'Occurs before the form region is displayed. 
'Use Me.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
'Use Me.OutlookFormRegion to get a reference to the form region.
Private Sub FormRegion1_FormRegionShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormRegionShowing
    obTask = Me.OutlookItem

    obDisTotal = obTask.UserProperties.Find("obDisTotal")
    If obDisTotal Is Nothing Then

    Else

        For i = 0 To obDisTotal.Value
            obDisID = obTask.UserProperties.Find("obDisID" & i)
            obDisCustCom = obTask.UserProperties.Find("obDisCustCom" & i)
            obDisDHCom = obTask.UserProperties.Find("obDisDHCom" & i)
            obDisUser = obTask.UserProperties.Find("obDisUser" & i)
            obDisTime = obTask.UserProperties.Find("obDisTime" & i)

            Dim Str(5) As String
            Dim Itm As ListViewItem
            Str(0) = obDisID.Value
            Str(1) = obDisCustCom.Value
            Str(2) = obDisDHCom.Value
            'Str(3) = NS.CurrentUser.ToString
            Str(4) = obDisTime.Value

            Itm = New ListViewItem(Str)
            ListView1.Items.Add(Itm)
        Next

    End If

End Sub


'Occurs when the form region is closed.   
'Use Me.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
'Use Me.OutlookFormRegion to get a reference to the form region.
Private Sub FormRegion1_FormRegionClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormRegionClosed

    For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        obDisID = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisID" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olInteger, True, True)
        obDisID.Value = itm.Index
        obDisCustCom = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisCustCom" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisCustCom.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(1).Text
        obDisDHCom = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisDHCom" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisDHCom.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(2).Text
        obDisUser = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisUser" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisUser.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(3).Text
        obDisTime = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisTime" & itm.Index, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True, Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
        obDisTime.Value = itm.SubItems.Item(4).Text
        obDisTotal = obTask.UserProperties.Add("obDisTotal", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olInteger, True, True)
        obDisTotal.Value = itm.Index
    Next

    obTask.Save()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form1 As New Form1()
    form1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

End Class